# Incremental build of a node-gyp project

Tags: c++, node-gyp

I'm fiddling around the [node-mariasql](https://github.com/mscdex/node-mariasql) source code, and would like to change some stuff and rebuild the project as I go. My intuitive approach was to just run `node-gyp rebuild` from the root of the project. Unfortunately, it looks like it always builds the whole project all over again, even if I just make a change on one of the source files :

```
~/Documents/workspace/node-mariasql$ node-gyp rebuild
gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
gyp info using node-gyp@3.4.0
gyp info using node@4.4.7 | linux | x64
...
make: Entering directory '/home/vagrant/Documents/workspace/node-mariasql/build'
  CXX(target) Debug/obj.target/taocrypt/deps/libmariadbclient/extra/yassl/taocrypt/src/aes.o
  CXX(target) Debug/obj.target/taocrypt/deps/libmariadbclient/extra/yassl/taocrypt/src/aestables.o
  ... (and so on...)

  CC(target) Debug/obj.target/zlib/deps/libmariadbclient/zlib/zutil.o
  AR(target) Debug/obj.target/deps/libmariadbclient/zlib/zlib.a
  COPY Debug/zlib.a
  CXX(target) Debug/obj.target/sqlclient/src/binding.o
../src/binding.cc:71:0: warning: "DEBUG" redefined [enabled by default]
  SOLINK_MODULE(target) Debug/obj.target/sqlclient.node
  COPY Debug/sqlclient.node
make: Leaving directory '/home/vagrant/Documents/workspace/node-
mariasql/build'
gyp info ok
```

The build process takes a little while, how can I make the project be built incrementally ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to documentation, `node-gyp rebuild` runs `clean`, `configure` and `build` commands all in a row. Just run `node-gyp build` to invoke make.

Comment: Thank you, that was a dumb question ^^

Comment: No, this is not a dumb question. I need this!